# Why do we experience more centripetal force when we make a sharp turn compared to a wide turn?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, speed, centripetal-force

If $F=m\omega^2r$, why do we experience more force when we decrease the radius of the turn?

Comment: $\omega = v/r$ , so  $F = mv^2/r$. Which means the force increases when the radius is smaller.

Comment: Because you don’t keep $\omega$ the same for turns with different radii.

Comment: Intuitively: Force is proportional to acceleration. Acceleration is the rate of change in velocity (and note: a change in _direction_ of motion is an acceleration even if you don't change your speed.) A sharp turn changes your direction more quickly than a broad turn, therefore, greater acceleration, greater force. See other comments for the physics-y (mathematical) explanation.

Comment: @WarreG im a little confused, does that mean we also expierence less centripetal force near the equator than the centripetal force near the pole?

Comment: No, because $\omega$ is the same and $v$ is not.

Comment: If $\omega$ is the same then force increases as radius increases. If $v$ is the same then force decreases as radius increases. You need to specify what is the same and what is different.